# Keymapping help needed with Apple keyboard on Windows 7 e.g. \ (backslash), at (@), pipe |

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, remapping

I would like some definitive advice with precise steps as to how to get the correct characters (i.e. those shown on the keys themselves) to show when I type with them.

Specifically I need keys with the following printed on them on the Apple keyboard to print the expected character when typed in Windows 7

- A key to the left of Enter with: . \ (backslash) pipe |
- key with at (@) above the 2 numeral key
- key with tilde ~ and back single quote
- there may be other keys needing adjusting

So for example, if I type shift+2 to get @ (printed on the key), I get double quotes instead - which is not what I want, obviously.

**Background**

I have a slim UK English Apple USB keyboard connected to a KVM switch shared by 2 Windows 7 PCs (a desktop and a netbook) and a UK English Apple MacBookPro. I like this keyboard and would like to share it with all 3 machines. All Machines are configured as UK/British/English keyboard/character set.

When the MacBookPro is booted via BootCamp into Windows 7, these keys behave as expected.

**Solutions I that have ALREADY looked at** (but may still work with extra guidance/advice)

I have already researched fairly extensively right here on superuser.com and elsewhere for solutions, three approaches in fact: I found SharpKeys and Microsoft's own tool Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4. I also looked at reproducing the successfull bootcamp setup:

1. When I tried **SharpKeys**, it seemed to me to be about making a key
   behave like another key rather than the actual character I wanted to
   be output. For example, with the @ sign above the 2 key. I found
   that I was just mapping the key onto itself - I couldn't actually
   choose what specific character I wanted to be output.
2. With **Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4**, the layout isn't
   quite like the keyboard I have and I had a go at doing some
   remapping but when using the testing facility I couldn't get any
   output. Not a fault of the program I just guess it's not suited to
   my setup. Though I would say I could do with a more Wizard-style
   guided setup to take me through the process, as it is not clear what
   all the things are that you would need to do - there is a .dll
   builder for example, do I need that? etc.
3. **Bootcamp** - the fact that the keyboard works perfectly with Windows 7
   on the MacBookPro tells me that it is possible. This would be
   because Apple have supplied drivers and setup to make this work. So
   I looked into trying to somehow extract out this perfect setup to
   reuse on the other Windows 7 machines. But I have not been
   successful so far. Also bear in mind that the Apple MacBookPro is
   running Windows 7 64 bit and the 2 other machines are both running
   Windows 7 32 bit (and I want them to stay that way as the netbook
   only support 32bit, the desktop has the maximum of 2Gb installed and
   an old Yamaha SW1000XG sound card which only has 32 bit drivers.)

So a definite answer, please on how I can reprogram keys to output different characters, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar problem in Windows 8 bootcamp, which is different from what you were asking, but I stumbled across this post when I was looking for the solution. 
The solution is to go to: 
Control panel --> Clock, language, and region --> Language 
Then, under "input method" you should only have "united states (apple)". Remove any other input methods.

[image: It should look like this]

Comment: Question is about Windows 7. This answer appears to be for some other version of Windows.

Comment: You're right, sorry, my solution is for windows 8. I ran into the same issue on my Windows 8 computer, and stumbled upon this forum posting looking for a solution. After figuring out the answer I came back here to share what worked for me.